# Receiving a NSUnknownKeyException error when running an Ionic build

Tags: ios, xcode, build, ionic-framework

I just completed a build of an Ionic application that has been exported using the `ionic build ios` function. Up till this point, I have not received any errors what so ever.

However when I try to run the application from XCode the app will not even boot up due to the following errors that I am receiving in the debugger:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x124d02c70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

As I am a bit of a beginner with Ionic and Cordova, I am not sure where to look. Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167865/xcode-is-giving-exception-when-ionic-3-app-run-on-ios-greater-than-9-3) with the same problem: you need to upgrade Cordova

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

Or, from link which that answer refers to: upgrade background plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode --nofetch
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Hope It helps!